# Keep duplicate keys in array when converting to XML - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am working with an API that use XML as input format. I am creating a JSON to XML from my end but i noticed that the array gets truncated because of same keys?

**This is how my JSON looks like:**

```
$order_data = array([
    "media_id" => 'FACE',
    "headline" => 'FACEBOOK FEBRUAR 2018',
    "agreement_id" => '****',
    "client_contact" => "Asim",
    "insertion" => [       
        "insertion_date" => '2018-10-08',
        "start_date" => '2018-10-08',
        "end_date" => "2018-10-09",
        "PO_number" => 150,
        "price_row" => [
            "price_code" => '000',
            "gross" => 11111
        ],
    ],
    "insertion" => [       
        "insertion_date" => '2018-09-25',
        "start_date" => '2018-09-25',
        "end_date" => "2018-10-10",
        "PO_number" => 150,
        "price_row" => [
            "price_code" => '000',
            "gross" => 10002345
        ],

    ],
]);
```

**And this is when i `print_r($order_data)`:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["media_id"]=>
    string(4) "FACE"
    ["headline"]=>
    string(21) "FACEBOOK FEBRUAR 2018"
    ["agreement_id"]=>
    string(4) "****"
    ["client_contact"]=>
    string(10) "Asim"
    ["insertion"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["insertion_date"]=>
      string(10) "2018-09-25"
      ["start_date"]=>
      string(10) "2018-09-25"
      ["end_date"]=>
      string(10) "2018-10-10"
      ["PO_number"]=>
      int(150)
      ["price_row"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["price_code"]=>
        string(3) "000"
        ["gross"]=>
        int(10002345)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The duplicate array `insertion` is removed, i know this is not an optional way to have duplicate keys but this is the API requirements. Anyone know how i can keep the duplicates?

*I also tried this format:*

```
"insertion" => [       
    "insertion_date" => '2018-10-08',
    "start_date" => '2018-10-08',
    "end_date" => "2018-10-09",
    "PO_number" => 150,
    "price_row" => [
        "price_code" => '000',
        "gross" => 11111
    ],
    "insertion_date" => '2018-09-25',
    "start_date" => '2018-09-25',
    "end_date" => "2018-10-10",
    "PO_number" => 150,
    "price_row" => [
        "price_code" => '000',
        "gross" => 10002345
    ],
],
```

**But still `print_r($order_data)` gives same as above**

Comment: It is _impossible_ to use the same key more than once on the same level. The latter one will always _overwrite_ the former.

Answer (score 1):

According you rule you can't give same name to the key in array on same level. But you can add multiple sub-arrays to that key like this:-

```
$order_data = array([
    "media_id" => 'FACE',
    "headline" => 'FACEBOOK FEBRUAR 2018',
    "agreement_id" => '****',
    "client_contact" => "Asim",
    "insertion" => [
        [
            "insertion_date" => '2018-10-08',
            "start_date" => '2018-10-08',
            "end_date" => "2018-10-09",
            "PO_number" => 150,
            "price_row" => [
                "price_code" => '000',
                "gross" => 11111
            ]
        ],
        [
            "insertion_date" => '2018-09-25',
            "start_date" => '2018-09-25',
            "end_date" => "2018-10-10",
            "PO_number" => 150,
            "price_row" => [
                "price_code" => '000',
                "gross" => 10002345
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Try this. I think this will help you.